# Change default sudo password timeout

Tags: sudo

When I run `sudo` and enter my password, a subsequent invocation of `sudo` within a few minutes will not need the password to be re-entered.

How can I change the default timeout to require the password again?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[`man sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.20/sudoers.man.html#User_Authentication) says:

> Once a user has been authenticated, [...] the user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time (5 minutes unless
>        overridden by the `timestamp_timeout` option).

To change the timeout, run, `sudo visudo` and add the line:

```
Defaults        timestamp_timeout=30
```

where `30` is the new timeout in minutes.

To always require a password, set to `0`. To set an infinite timeout, set the value to be negative.

To totally disable the prompt for a password for user `ravi`:

```
Defaults:ravi      !authenticate
```

Comment: Huh, I got as far as `timestamp_timeout` when searching the man pages myself, but I didn't know to include `Defaults`. What told you that in the manual?

Answer (score 33):

`sudo visudo` is to modify the default configuration file directly, but in the file has suggestion below

> Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of directly modifying this file.

So, **better way** is

```bsh
cd /etc/sudoers.d
sudo visudo -f user_name
```

Add the content

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=(number)
```

`(number)` is the new timeout in **minutes**.

> **timestamp_timeout** (man 5 sudoers)
>
> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a fractional component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 15.  Set this to 0 to always prompt for a password.  If set to a value less than 0 the user's time stamp will not expire until the system is rebooted.  This can be used to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via “sudo -v” and “sudo -k” respectively.

Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, and exit using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: Good catch.. +1 to you as well. Yes, "conf.d" format/type areas are always the best and preferred way to edit system/service configs (when it's available).

Comment: This doesnt work in tmux. Any idea how to make it recognizable in tmux.

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit /etc/sudoers. For those who don't use vi, you should edit this file (on some flavors of Linux) with a terminal command like this:

```
sudo EDITOR=gedit visudo
```

Then add or change `timestamp_timeout`:

```
# After authenticating, this is the amount of time after which
# sudo will prompt for a password again in the same terminal
Defaults    timestamp_timeout=30
```

Comment: The right™ way to avoid `vi`, would be setting the `$EDITOR` variable to something else.  The idea of `visudo` is not to call `vi`, but to keep people from locking themselves (and anyone else depending on `sudo`) out of their `root` account by 1) copying `/etc/sudoers` to a temporary file, 2) calling `$EDITOR` on this file, 3) *running a syntax check on this file* and 4) eventually replacing `/etc/sudoers` with the updated version.

Comment: `visudo`'s documentation says this: "Normally, visudo does not honor the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables unless they contain an editor in the aforementioned editors list" - and the list defaults to only `vi`, while allowing any editor is said to be a security hole. But I can confim that `sudo EDITOR=gedit visudo` works on my CentOS 7.2 box. The syntax check it provides is certainly a Good Thing.

Comment: Ah, yeah, thank you for the (further) clarification, I missed that. But IIRC you can also change the default editor in `sudoers` itself - just for the record. I'm sure the syntax check will tell. ;)

Comment: The right way is just to spend 5 minutes a learn the basics of vi/vim. There is no question it will be there when you type `visudo`, but other editors may not. All you really need to know is vi has 2 modes, command (default) and insert modes. You tap `'i'` to get into *insert mode* (edit as normal) and tap `ESC` to return to *command mode*. Then `:wq` to write and quit or just `:q` to quit and to discard changes and quit it's just `:q!`. When all else fails, tap `ESC` to return to command mode...