# sudo su - anotherusername not prompting for password

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I using Redhat linux. I am trying to run the following command and would like to know why it is not prompting for password?

Here is what I am doing. I open the terminal window and enter my username and password. After that I run the following command

```
sudo su - anotherusername
```

The command runs successfully without prompting for password of anotherusername. I want to know why I don't get password prompt?

Are there any circumstances where I will get password prompt for anotherusername?

Or Is there a different command that will prompt me for anotherusername password?

I mistakenly posted this question in StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632690/sudo-su-username-not-prompting-for-password 
and I was told that if my username is part of sudoers group then I will not get password prompt.

Just want to confirm if that is the only reason or there are other reasons as well for not receiving password prompt.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Comment: Possibly: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382060/117549

Answer (score 3):

`sudo su` runs `su` as `root`; thus there is no need for `su` to ask a password.

The question might be why `sudo` does not ask for a password (the invoking user's or `root`'s). The output of `sudo -l` may explain that. Or `sudo` has been invoked before and considers the formerly entered password still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the username of the user running the sudo command in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
$ sudo grep yourusername /etc/sudoers
yourusername    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If the output of that `grep` command contains `NOPASSWD:`, then use the `visudo` command to edit and remove the `NOPASSWD:` from that line.

Also, you'll be prompted for the password of the user running the `sudo` command, not the password of the account that you're trying to login to.

Comment: `sudo -iu anotherusername` would be somewhat easier, though