# How do I make myself an admin or get root privileges so I don't have to keep typing the root password?

Tags: centos, sudo

I have to use sudo a lot, and it gets exhausting typing the password when I've already entered it plenty of times. How do I make it so that once I've entered it once, it won't ask me again? I'm on Centos 7.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to go about this.  Here are a few:

### Disable the password prompts

Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/579296/how-do-i-disable-the-sudo-password-prompt)

### Alter the timeout

Ref: [Change default sudo password timeout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382060/change-default-sudo-password-timeout)

### Elevate to `root`

```
sudo -i
```

This latter option is the closest match to your question, I suppose, but you may well find the timeout meets your needs.

Comment: I think I prefer changing the default sudo password timeout. First off, do I just add the line Defaults        timestamp_timeout=30 anywhere in the file?

Comment: If there's an existing `Defaults` entry, you should append that.  Otherwise I'd tend to stick it up near the top, but I don't think it particularly matters where it goes.

Comment: I always use `sudo -s`. What's the difference with `sudo -i`?

Comment: Can’t say I’ve ever used `-s` that I recall, but `-i` simulates the initial login, so presumably sets up the environment akin to if you did `sudo su -`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -s
```

Will leave you as root, be careful

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't it make sense to use `sudo -i` instead to ensure `root`'s environment is set appropriately?

Comment: the only difference i can see right now is when iam using sudo -s , iam not losing my current working directory

Answer (score 0):

You could enable login for the `root` account. Be aware that there's a reason (or more than one) that this is disabled by default; you'll have to be sure what you do when you work as `root` permanently (even if it's only in a single terminal window). I absolutely discourage to start a Desktop environment or run user applications (like Office, browsers etc.) with `root` privileges, or otherwise make a habit of working as `root` by default. Log in on console when you need to, and log out as soon as you're done. Make sure the login features a different prompt than normal users, using the hash as prompt sign, and red color e. g. for the hostname.

That said, setting a password for `root` should be as easy as

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

After that you can use [`su`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) to log in from a normal user account, or better `su -l` in order to load the profile. As additional security measure you should make sure that direct login via SSH is disabled; check `PermitRootLogin` in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html).

More details (should mostly be applicable to other distros, too): https://askubuntu.com/a/44419/568304

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, which I do not recomend, due to security reasons, is to delete the password from the root user:

```
$ sudo passwd -d root
```

From the passwd(1) man page:

> -d
>
> This is a quick way to delete a password for an account. It will set the named account passwordless. Available to root only.

See [passwd(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd)

**Edit**

As stated out in [trentcl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/366333/trentcl) commentary, the solution that I propose won't meet the user requirement.

Instead it will disable the possibility to log in as root. In this case the only way to gain root access will be through sudo. Some Linux distros make root passwordless by default.

Comment: Passwordless doesn't mean you can log in without a password, it means you can't log in as that user at all. If you do this it just makes `sudo` the only way to get root access (because the password you type at a `sudo` prompt is your own, not root's). Some Linux distros make root passwordless by default.